# Shaded half-ellipsoids in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can simulate a set of balls (blue). I can also simulate a set of ellipsoids (yellow}.
How to obtain a set of half-ellipsoids?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,pgffor}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x  in {1,2,3,4}
        \shadedraw [ball color=blue] (\x,2.5,13) 
        circle (0.45cm);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=2]

\foreach \x  in {1,2,3,4}
        \shadedraw [ball color=yellow] (\x,2.5,13) 
        circle (0.45cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Half how? Horizontally or vertically (or even in another way)? You may use `\clip` with the shape you want.

Comment: @SebGlav I need only the upper parts of them, lying on the plane (to be added to the picture) where the balls lie. Any version of rotation a fixed curve, e.g., parabola, is also OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to scale anything, but shading an appropriate shape, like this:

[image: Shading half-ellipsoids]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,pgffor}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x  in {1,2,3,4}
        \shadedraw [ball color=blue] (\x,2.5,13) 
        circle (0.45cm);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x  in {1,2,3,4} 
    \shadedraw [ball color=yellow] (-0.45+\x,2.5,13) arc(-180:0:0.45 and 0.225) arc(0:180:0.45 and 0.9) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it is a good idea!